# matlab plot multiple functions

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab and I'm trying to plot a few functions on a single plot to compare their rate of growth:

```
n = [1:100];

plot(n, 2.^(2.^n), 'b')
hold
plot(n, 2.^n, 'r');
hold
plot(n, n.^log2(n), 'g') 
hold   
plot(n, n.^2, 'm')
```

But all I get is only the last function.

Answer (score 5):

change your `hold` command to be `hold on`. `hold` by itself just toggles the hold-state of the figure, meaning if you had:

```
plot(...)   %plot 1
hold
plot(...)   %plot 2
hold
plot(...)   %plot 3
hold
plot(...)   %plot 4
```

This is equivalent to:

```
plot(n, 2.^(2.^n), 'b')   %plot 1
hold on
plot(n, 2.^n, 'r')   %plot 2 --> figure is held
hold off
plot(n, n.^log2(n), 'g')   %plot 3 --> figure isn't held
hold on
plot(n, n.^2, 'm')   %plot 3 --> figure is held
```

So in the end, based on your original code you should have 2 lines plotted. Since one grows at a much faster rate than the other, you may have to look closely to see the slower one. On that note, when you get your hold's in order and plot all 4 lines, your 1st plot will grow so quickly that you won't really see much of the other 3 lines, just as a heads up.

Also, you'll only need to have 1 hold command for the figure; you don't need to re-apply it after each plot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he won't see much of the first one either; it will exceed the range of `double` very very quickly (between `n == 9` and `n == 10` is my guess).

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right, n == 9 yields the last non-infinite result (on my machine)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = [1:100];
figure 
hold on;
plot(n, 2.^(2.^n), 'b');
plot(n, 2.^n, 'r');
plot(n, n.^log2(n), 'g'); 
plot(n, n.^2, 'm');
hold off;
```

Generating a new figure window is useful down the line when you want more than one window to open. After you generate a new figure window, you can turn hold on for as long as you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is put everything in one "plot" command:

```
n = [1:100];

plot(n, 2.^(2.^n), 'b', n, 2.^n, 'r', n, n.^log2(n), 'g', n, n.^2, 'm');
```